# JSON Request via .ajax - How to utilize

Tags: jquery, json, ajax

I'm lost :-( I receive a successful response from an AJAX request via CORS, but I have no idea how to actually use the JSON file I'm acquiring.

All of my alerts are working. How would I cache the received JSON file as a function/variable?

```
$(function(){
    var pulseRestApiGetQueryUri = "https://doesntmatter/api/v1/search.json?q=" + encodeURIComponent("%23c2alerts");
    $.support.cors = true;                                                                                    
    $.ajax({
         type: "GET",
         headers: {'X-API-Key': 'com.amazon.c2alerts'},                                               
         url: pulseRestApiGetQueryUri,                                                                         
         timeout: 10000, // 10 seconds
         contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",                                                       
         dataType: "json",
         xhrFields: {withCredentials: true},

         success: function(posts) {
            alert('SUCCESS');
         },
         error: function(jqXhr, status, errorThrown) {
            alert('ERROR');
         },
         beforeSend: function() {
            alert('BUSY');
         },
         complete: function() {
            alert('COMPLETE');
         }
    });
});
```

Every alert works except for 'SUCCESS'. I can do whatever I want after 'complete'. How do I get the structure readily available for HTML manipulation and where do I put it?

Here are two sample entries from my JSON.

```
{
     "author":{
        "namespace":"user",
        "name":"nichazel",
        "string_form":"user:nichazel",
        "full_name":"Nicholas Hazel"
     },
     "body":"Have an idea? We are trying to collect new and fresh ideas for process improvement. Please jot down ANY ideas you may have. We will discuss them in our team meeting this afternoon -urgent #c2alerts",
     "topics":[
        {
           "namespace":"hashtag",
           "name":"c2alerts",
           "string_form":"hashtag:c2alerts"
        }
     ],
     "source":"web",
     "post_id":"30d97e00-596f-4936-ade9-557db0e907df",
     "created":"2013-07-31T20:18:22Z",
     "votes":{
        "up_votes":2,
        "down_votes":0,
        "up_voters":[
           {
              "namespace":"user",
              "name":"bostrom",
              "string_form":"user:bostrom"
           },
           {
              "namespace":"user",
              "name":"eakerry",
              "string_form":"user:eakerry"
           }
        ],
        "down_voters":[

        ]
     }
  },
  {
     "author":{
        "namespace":"user",
        "name":"chayavic",
        "string_form":"user:chayavic",
        "full_name":"Sam Chayavichitsilp"
     },
     "body":"Happy Friday C2. Retail AHOD (L2) - No Stand-Up Meeting for the entire team.\n#c2alerts",
     "topics":[
        {
           "namespace":"hashtag",
           "name":"c2alerts",
           "string_form":"hashtag:c2alerts"
        }
     ],
     "source":"web",
     "post_id":"a05d96ae-2c6e-4054-989f-d25a74bfc553",
     "created":"2013-07-26T14:57:18Z"
  },
```

And here is a sample of it working via getJSON (which I can't use because it's not CORS):

```
    $.getJSON('jsonURL',function(data){

        $.each(data.results, function(i, item) {
        alert(item.body);
        });

    });
```

The same principles won't apply to the regular AJAX request. Any ideas how to get the JSON as part of the DOM, or at least parsed so I can utilize the fields?

Comment: Move the `$.each` from `$.getJSON` and place it in the success callback. ...

Answer (score 0):

Use `JSON.parse()` to convert strings in JSON format to objects:

```
success: function(posts) {
    someVariable = JSON.parse(posts);
}
```

If your success callback is not firing, then you have another problem. What is the output from the error?

```
error: function(jqXhr, status, errorThrown) {
    console.log(jqXhr);
    console.log(status);
    console.log(errorThrown);
}
```

Comment: Surprisingly, very very bland...
I received an Error 500 - Internal Service error.
Other than that, 'errorThrown' is undefined:

Object { readyState=0, status=0, statusText="error"}
error
(an empty string)
completed
test2.html (line 34)

Comment: Well, that at least explains why your success function isn't firing. I am unable to help you further without more specific details. You could try messing with the headers or dropping parameters (e.g. the `dataType` parameter).

Comment: 500 error means server-side error unrelated to jquery. use server-side debugging to get more details.

Answer (score 0):

It's sending SUCCESS since you are asking it to be alerted. For iterating over the JSON, JSON can be stored in a variable and since you have `posts` already you can use it to iterate using a loop in the success function as follows:

```
for(var i=0;i<posts.length;i++){
    alert(posts[i].author);
    alert(posts[i].body);
    //Etc. Other fields can be well added.
}
```

Comment: When I look at the files within FireBug, I look at the file and the 'response' for the JSON file shows all of my data. Is there any circumstance when it would pull all of the data but never trigger 'SUCCESS'?

Comment: @NicholasHazel Yes, in that case ERROR would be triggered.